# what does this nm output mean?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a shared object file built using g++ as shown below.

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -lpthread -O1 -std=c++11 -c AOTelemetry.cpp -L /home -I /opt/java7/include/ -I /opt/java7/include/linux/ -lstdc++ -ldl -lcsfutil -lcsfthread -ldata -lservices -lserviceutil -levent -lhealth -o AOTelemetry.so
```

The nm utility when run on the object file displays a lot of memory address references( that's what I think they are) as zeros. What does this mean?

```
0000000000000000 V typeinfo name for std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
0000000000000000 V vtable for ProcessJob
0000000000000000 V vtable for NativePlugin
0000000000000000 V vtable for AOTelemetryPlugin
0000000000000000 V vtable for Shutdown 
0000000000000000 V vtable for BdtBuffer
             U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
             U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info
0000000000000000 V vtable for std::_Sp_counted_ptr<ProcessJob*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
0000000000000000 V vtable for std::_Sp_counted_ptr<Shutdown*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
0000000000000000 V vtable for std::_Sp_counted_ptr<BdtBuffer*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
0000000000000000 V vtable for std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
```

Comment: Did you see the [man pages for nm](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm)?

Comment: Yes I did. It just says that the symbol type V is a weak object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend reading a man page or an only tutorial/documentation about `nm`.

From [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-nm-command/) tutorial:

> The nm commands provides information on the symbols being used in an object file or executable file.
> The default information that the ‘nm’ command provides is :
>
> - Virtual address of the symbol
> - A character which depicts the symbol type. If the character is in lower case then the symbol is local but if the character is in upper case then the symbol is external
> - Name of the symbol